# Why is my range function showing an undefined value after the the loop should have closed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined, return-type

I'm trying to make a function that will store all integers from 0 up to and including x in an array.

```
function range(x){
  for(var counter = 0; counter <= x; counter++)
  show(counter);
}
var rangeArray = [range(4)];
show(rangeArray);
```

This will give me 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 (but not in an array :(), then, as if taunting me, put undefined in an array all by its lonesome.

Where is this undefined coming from, and why don't the other values go in the array?

Comment: `range(x)` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
function range(x){
  var result = [];
  for(var counter = 0; counter <= x; counter++) {
    result.push(counter);
    show(counter);
  }
  return result;
}
var rangeArray = range(4);
show(rangeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions always `return undefined` when you have not explicitly called `return`. Except in the case when you called the `function` with `new`. In that case the function returns `this` (a reference to the object that was created).

```
function foo() {

}

foo() // returns undefined
new foo() // returns a reference to the object that was created
```

**Convention dictates** that if a function is to be used as a constructor that it is capitalized

```
function Foo() {
    this.x = 5;
    // return this; // is implicit 
}
```

This convention is helpful because really bad stuff will happen if you call the `function Foo` and forget to quantify it with `new`.

```
x = 42
Foo() // this mistake is easier to spot if the function is capitalized
// x is now equal to 5.
x = 42
f = new Foo()
// x is still 42 and f.x is 5
```

**Why do the values not go into the array?**

A program can not simply print values into its own source code. To do so would be mind bogglingly impossible to reason about. The other answers on this page are both good solutions to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have a basic function called range that is similar in functionality to Pythons range function.  This is a simple and effective array generator.

```
// Function to return array from 0-x
function range(x) {
    // Start with an empty array
    var arr = [],
        i = -1;
    // Loop through values from 0-X
    for(;i++ < x;) {
        // Add number to array
        arr.push(i)
    }
    // Return array 
    return arr;
}

var rangeArr = range(5)  //returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Hiya. This may well provide a solution... but generally it's considered to be Good Form to provide an explanation for why this solves the problem. Don't forget that total n00bs may google and come to this page too, so an explanation will let them tell if this solution will be good for them too :)

Comment: Good point, I'll add one.  I'm a n00b to stack exchange but I've become point obsessed...

Comment: It's great for that ;)

Comment: Maybe I am nit picking but the point of the question was not "how do I write a simple range function?" it was "Why is `undefined` the only thing in the array?"

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle.  Right now your range function is a little confusing and doesn't return anything.